# Can I set custom ports for a Kubernetes ingress to listen on besides 80 / 443?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I don't mean being able to route to a specific port, I mean to actually change the port the ingress listens on.

Is this possible? How? Where is this documented?

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? How are you deploying it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No. From the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress):

> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type Service.Type=NodePort or Service.Type=LoadBalancer.

It may be possible to customize a LoadBalancer on a cloud provider like AWS to listen on other ports.

Comment: It is possible to customise the _ingress controller_ to listen on any port, but not possible to modify ports in a ingress definition

Answer (score 23):

I assume you are using [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). In this case, during installation, instead of doing a `kubectl apply` in the official yaml like [this is one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml), you can try downloading the yaml and changing the port. The file above, which is used for an L4 AWS ELB, would become like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - port: {custom port 1}
      targetPort: http
    - port: {custom port 2}
      targetPort: https
```

An alternative is to use a more powerful ingress controller.
[Here is a list](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) of different controllers.
My personal choice is [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/getting-started/). If you follow the getting-started page, you just need to change the service definition for the port of your choice:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
   - port: {custom port}
     targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    service: ambassador
```

Answer (score 13):

The ingress controller handling the ingress can have its ports  changed via the ingress controllers deployment.

An [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) definition is backed by an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). The ingress controller is deployed with normal Kubernetes objects so will have a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) associated with it that exposes ports for the ingress controller.

The [`kubernetes/ingress-nginx static deploys`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/deploy/static/provider) have a `deploy.yaml` with a Service type `LoadBalancer`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
```

Modify the ports the load balancer is configured with, in `spec.ports[*].port` in the external service, however that is deployed.

Comment: Download the `deploy.yaml` from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy make the change above then `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml`

Comment: Is this same thing allowed for GKE ingress?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Helm to deploy the Kubernetes `ingress-nginx` controller, you can do this to change the ports from their defaults of 80 and 443 in a Helm values override file:

```
ingress-nginx:
  enabled: true
  ...
  controller:
    service:
      ports:
        http: 8123
        https: 9456
```

See here: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx#values

In this example, any services exposed through the ingress are now available on ports 8123 (http) and 9456 (https).