# Helm - how to set custom service port for ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have very simple yaml to create ingress controller:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

I am not sure why is defined like this but it's defined in that format and it works.
This question is not similar to this one [Can I set custom ports for a Kubernetes ingress to listen on besides 80 / 443?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243121/can-i-set-custom-ports-for-a-kubernetes-ingress-to-listen-on-besides-80-443) because the  YAML definition is totally different and I do not know how to set configuration within my YAML definition without "kind" specification.

I now create ingress controller and it creates IC.

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml
 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

Output presents that it listens on port 80 and 443.

```
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller    LoadBalancer   10.10.36.81     10.13.17.35   80:31312/TCP,443:30653/TCP
```

I tried also like this:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  spec:
    ports:
      - name:"proxy-tcp"
        port:9000
```

I do not need HTTP or HTTPS request.
I do not need to have publich IP address.
I need to have my ingress controller running on port 9000.

I tried these options:
in command line to run with these properties:

```
--set defaultBackend.service.port=9000
    
or 
    
--set defaultBackend.service.servicePort=9000
```

but it didn't changed the value - still 80 and 443.

and also - no progress.
How I can make my IC to listen on TCP port number 9000?
Thank you

Comment: Is this your helm chart https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx

Comment: @mchawre yes it is. Do you know how I can force the IC to be run on Port 9000? All my methods previously failed