# Helm - documentation specification for very unusual and not regular Kubernetes YAML format

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

on microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-internal-ip) I found that I should define this Helm YAML file for creating Kubernetes Ingress Controller:

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: 10.240.0.42
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

So you can easily notice it DOES NOT have usual Kubernetes **apiVersion and kind** specification.
and after, on the same link that I need to execute the helm command to create Ingress:

```
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    -f internal-ingress.yaml \
..............
```

As you see - suggested Helm file is not very usual, but I would like to stick to those official Microsoft instructions!
Again, it does not have specification for creating Ingress Controller using the regular apiVersion and kind notation like on many links and examples that can be found on the internet.

https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

[Can I set custom ports for a Kubernetes ingress to listen on besides 80 / 443?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243121/can-i-set-custom-ports-for-a-kubernetes-ingress-to-listen-on-besides-80-443)

So I really feel very very confused!!! Can you please help me on this - I need to set it's Port but I really could not find specification documentation and examples for this one YAML Microsoft example which actually works!!!

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: 10.240.0.42
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Where and how I can find correct syntax how I can "translate" regular "apiVersion" and "kind" specification into this?

Why they are making confusion in this way with this different format???
Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-f` does not set a "manifest" as stated in the Microsoft docs. As per `helm install --help`:

> `-f`, `--values` strings               specify values in a YAML file
> or a URL (can specify multiple)

The default [values file](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) contains the values to be passed into the chart.

User-supplied values with `-f` are merged with the default value files to generate the final manifest. The precedence order is:

> - The values.yaml file in the chart
> - If this is a subchart, the values.yaml file of a parent chart
> - A values file if passed into helm install or helm upgrade with the -f flag (helm install -f myvals.yaml ./mychart)
> - Individual parameters passed with --set (such as helm install --set foo=bar ./mychart)

> The list above is in order of specificity: values.yaml is the default, which can be overridden by a parent chart's values.yaml, which can in turn be overridden by a user-supplied values file, which can in turn be overridden by --set parameters.

What are you doing is overriding the `controller` value on top of the default values file. You can find the original/default values for the *ingress-nginx* chart [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml).

Comment: thank you so much for this very, very useful response. You mentioned that I override the default values file - that means that I will not be able to propagate those values "loadBalancerIP" and "azure-load-balancer" through the -f, --values strings correct? 
Can you please tell one more thig which I am struggling for 10 days - how I can in this way set/change the default port on which IngressController is being run? It always sets 80 and 443.
I tried with `--set defaultBackend.service.port=9000` and `--set defaultBackend.service.servicePort=9000` but it didn't work!!!

Comment: And of course I marked response:)
But because of this values chart format I really got lost.I even opened a question for this Port modification but someone not so kind reported that as duplicated although it is not! I am trying to specify the PORT of the Ingress Controller in a completely different way  through these --values method but without success, my Ingress controller on `get services` command always returns port 80 but I need port 9000 for TCP connection 
 - NO HTTP needed at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113368/helm-how-to-set-custom-service-port-for-ingress-controller

Comment: @AndreyDonald You can propagate all your custom values at once using the values file. You can try to set the [`service.ports`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/a7fb791132a0dee285b47d0041f4f9acf1e7cff8/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L387) value. Give it a try by specifying [this value file](https://gist.github.com/eduardobaitello/405eaf1dc36518be96328d688207918d) with `-f `, please.

Comment: Thank you Eduardo. I will give it a try. I should set port 9000 on http: field regardless that I need that port 9000 for TCP connection? We will not use Ingress Controller as Web Server - we just need to have it for accessing to our container from different private virtual network. That is maybe a thing which makes all this confusion... Thank you so much for your kindness and willingness to help!

Comment: @AndreyDonald the nginx-ingress is not meant to proxy forward raw TCP connections... It's better that you consider using the [HAProxy](https://github.com/haproxytech/helm-charts) instead :)

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, I will go through this....but actually my Azure Cloud Team instructed me to implement nginx-ingress (based on Microsoft docs for "an internal virtual network") They state I should install Ingress and they will set up the Reverse Proxy in order for connection to be established. I understood Ingress is more for HTTP but it seemed to me it can fit perfectly fine for TCP as well. So do you still think your configuration with `ports: https: 9000` is applicable for my use case? thanks

Comment: @AndreyDonald I don't have experience on using Ingress to TCP proxy,  so I can't opine on this one; sorry. As I commented on the gist file, you can find in which templates the values will be used. It's up to you to analyze if it fits your purpose. If you need more help with helm values, just let me know and we can move this discussion to a proper place :)

Comment: @EduardoBaitello can you maybe assist me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588305/kubernetes-different-services-for-tcp-connection-outside-the-cluster/ thanks