# kind cluster cannot bind port 80 on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, windows-10, kind

I'm using local Kubernetes cluster with kind. I try to use Ingress and follow the next instruction from official documentation:
https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/#create-cluster

My cluster configuration:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: InitConfiguration
    nodeRegistration:
      kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 80
```

But looks like I cannot using port 80 on Windows:

```
kind create cluster --config=.\kubernetes\kind-cluster.yaml
Creating cluster "kind" ...
 • Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.21.1)   ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.21.1) 
 • Preparing nodes    ...
 ✗ Preparing nodes 
ERROR: failed to create cluster: docker run error: command "docker run --hostname kind-control-plane --name kind-control-plane --label io.x-k8s.kind.role=control-plane --privileged --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --security-opt apparmor=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run --volume /var --volume /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --detach --tty --label io.x-k8s.kind.cluster=kind --net kind --restart=on-failure:1 --init=false --publish=0.0.0.0:80:80/TCP --publish=127.0.0.1:55805:6443/TCP -e KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf kindest/node:v1.21.1@sha256:69860bda5563ac81e3c0057d654b5253219618a22ec3a346306239bba8cfa1a6" failed with error: exit status 125

Command Output: db8cabb573332b7f0466a0461c4b2e687350400f71bb2b04b98b337900180310
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

So the main question: can I change that port to something another (30080)? And how to access services after that?

---

Edit 1:
tried to use 30080 port and apply commands from Documentation link: Cluster starts, Ingress (using nginx) starts, but I can't access service:

```
curl localhost/foo
curl : Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

curl http://localhost:30080/foo
curl: Underlying connection closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

I suppose the reason is that Ingress use port 80 by default:

```
 kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   *       localhost   80      5m46s
```

Comment: `can I change that port to something another (30080)?` what happened when you did?

Comment: @rkosegi Thank you for reply! Cluster creates successfully, Ingress pod starts successfully, but I can't use `curl localhost/foo` or `curl http://localhost:30080/foo` - get errors HTTP 404 or `curl: Underlying connection closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

Comment: I think if you update your question with that info, you will get better chance for answer from someone

Comment: @rkosegi added info. Looks like Ingress use port 80 anyway

Comment: Ingress will use only [80 or 443 ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243121/can-i-set-custom-ports-for-a-kubernetes-ingress-to-listen-on-besides-80-443).  Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Hi! I'm using v1.22 on kind v0.11.1 go1.16.4

Comment: Please add your ingress yaml file.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Hi! Yep, I found the solution :)

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Btw I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere on the Internet, I found a solution (unfortunately, I did not save the original link). The minimal implementation of the solution for my case is as follows:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 80
    hostPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1
  - containerPort: 443
    hostPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    listenAddress: 127.0.0.1
```

This allows me to reach my services using:
`localhost:8080` or `127.0.0.1:8080`.
Suppose `443` port is for https, but I'm not using it at the current moment so can't check it's workability.