# Kubernetes Ingress auth-signin redirect to different port

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Does anyone know how to redirect it to a host:port?
For me the redirect is happening only to the host (ie metrics.staging.com) and I want to redirect to metrics.staging.com:9099 ?

My ingress:
` nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://oauth2-qa.staging.com:9043/oauth2/start?rd=https://$host$request_uri

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://oauth2-qa.staging.com:9043/oauth2/auth

My whitlist-domain and cookie-domain are both set to .staging.com

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can find some answers in this other question: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243121/can-i-set-custom-ports-for-a-kubernetes-ingress-to-listen-on-besides-80-443)