How to configure nginix ingress to listen for HTTPS traffic on multiple ports (443 and 5601) on AKS
I am configuring NGINX as an ingress on Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS). I will have multiple services I need to expose through the ingress using host based routing rules.  One of the services uses HTTPS traffic but on a nonstandard port (5601).
I am using helm to deploy NGINX onto AKS and have modified the helm chart values.yaml file so that the k8s service and associated Azure LB listen on 5601 by defining the service.customPorts parameter. This created a LB based service in Azure that properly showed a rule for traffic on 5601.

I also updated controller.customports which updated the controller deployment to listen on containerport 5601.

After that I defined my normal ingress file which points to the back end service.

Unfortunately the traffic doesn't flow through however.  I checked the pod logs for the nginx controller and it wasn't even logging receiving the requests on 5601 while all the other services on 443 were working as expected.
I dumped the running nginx config using:
kubectl exec -it -n nginx mypodnamewenthere -- nginx -T
and when I look through the details the servers section shows that the nginx software itself is only listening on 80 & 443.  What do I need to do to get the actual nginx server software to listen on 5601 for ssl traffic IN ADDITION to 443?
server {
    listen 80;listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;
    ssl_certificate_key $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;

    server_tokens on;

    server_name redactedservername;


Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243121/can-i-set-custom-ports-for-a-kubernetes-ingress-to-listen-on-besides-80-443#:~:text=No.%20From%20the%20kubernetes%20documentation%3A%20An%20Ingress%20does,provider%20like%20AWS%20to%20listen%20on%20other%20ports. and share your complete configmap, values.yaml and ingress yaml and kibana yaml in code format in your question and output of kubectl exec -it -n ingress-basic  -- nginx -T | grep 5601

As per Nginx document, usually this is the way to configure the nginx ingress controller to listen on port 5601.
install the nginx ingress controller
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-basic --create-namespace


Create/edit the values.yaml for the Helm Chart Values with the following content
controller:
  config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
  service:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local
    customPorts:
      - port: 5601
        targetPort: 5601
        protocol: TCP
        name: custom-https
  extraPorts:
    - port: 5601
      targetPort: 5601
      protocol: TCP
      name: custom-https


Since you already have a setup, upgrade or compare the existing nginx ingress controller with the custom values as shown above
helm upgrade nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-basic -f values.yaml

Create / edit your configmap.yaml with the following content to include the server block for port 5601.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-basic
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "30s"
  proxy-read-timeout: "120s"
  proxy-send-timeout: "120s"
  client-max-body-size: "50m"
  server-snippet: |
    server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      listen [::]:443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;
      ssl_certificate_key $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;
      server_tokens on;
      server_name redactedservername;
    }
    server {
      listen 5601 ssl;
      listen [::]:5601 ssl;
      ssl_certificate $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;
      ssl_certificate_key $secret_dir_path/elasticsearch-tls-secret-nginx-redactedservername;
      server_tokens on;
      server_name redactedservername;
    }



Restart or delete the old nginx ingress controller pods and create an ingress.yaml file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: redactedhostname
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kibana-kb-https
            port:
              number: 5601
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - redactedhostname
    secretName: tls-secret-nginx-redactedhostname


exec into the pod and verify
kubectl exec -it -n ingress-basic <nginx-controller-pod-name> -- nginx -T | grep 5601

